# PHP dynamic multidimensional arrays - getting data into the right format

Tags: php, arrays, format

I'm having a terrible time trying to massage an array of data into the format a third-party service requires. I can't change the way the data comes into the function so I need to manipulate it then send it off. I've managed to hack it into a state where its almost correct with the exception that it only takes the first value of the arrays and ignores the rest. I think this is because I'm overwriting the values but I don't know how to solve it.

I'm pretty new to PHP and think I'm missing some core array methods or something here so any input would be greatly appreciated

Data going into the function ($data)

```
Array (
    [checkbox_customfield_11363] => Array
        (
            [random unknown string] => Apple
            [random unknown string] => Orange
            [random unknown string] => Banana
        )

    [checkbox_customfield_11339] => Array
        (
            [random unknown string] => Peas
            [random unknown string] => Potatos

        )
)
```

The function that should be massaging the data into the required format. The first foreach loop just removes the first part of the name of each array, It works as intended - might not be the cleanest though. Its the second foreach and below that I'm struggling with.

```
public function createCheckBoxField($data)
{
    $checkbox_matches = array();
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        if (preg_match("/checkbox/", $key)) {
            $newKey = explode('_', $key, 2);
            $checkbox_matches[$newKey[1]] = $value;
        }
    }

    $checkboxes = array();
    foreach ($checkbox_matches as $key1 => $value1) {

        foreach ($value1 as $test) {
            $checkboxes += [$key1 => [["value" => $test]]];
        }
    }
    return $checkboxes;
}
```

Code currently returns

```
Array
(
    [customfield_11363] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [value] => Apple
                )

        )

    [customfield_11339] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [value] => Peas
                )

        )

)
```

I need it to be returning

```
Array
(
    [customfield_11363] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [value] => Apple
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [value] => Orange
                )
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [value] => Banana
                )

        )

    [customfield_11339] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [value] => Peas
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [value] => Potato
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: You have not provided the input data. If you ask on stackoverflow, please create the example from scratch with as little code as necessary to demonstrate the issue containing all data to reproduce the issue.

Comment: The very first code block is the input data.

Comment: The very first code block is no code at all. It's a syntax error. It also does not specify the input array properly as it's ambiguous.

Comment: It's not a syntax error, it is a dump (print_r) of the value $data which cannot be modified. $data is the input data.

Comment: `print_r` does not output in a syntax-error-free manner, `var_export` does. Next to that, this is ***not*** the prin_r output, you redacted it which makes it unuseable. But you seem that learning resistant that you assume all the bad with my comments. You should perhaps think about why I comment at all.

Comment: @hakre: looks like `print_r` output to me.

Comment: @AbraCadaver: print_r does not output duplicate keys like three times `random unknown string`.

Comment: @hakre: I see.  I took `random unknown string` to mean `random unknown string` not `'random unknown string'`. :-)

Comment: @hakre: I'm not sure there's any value in chastising someone who has already made it quite clear that they are new to PHP...   explaining the syntax issue is valuable however. Perhaps a little more calm to complement the clarity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the `preg_match` etc (because you haven't shown what it is meant to do), but given your input and desired output this should work:

```
foreach($data as $key => $array) {
    foreach($array as $value) {
        $result[$key][] = array('value' => $value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem why you see only the first element is because of the array union operator you're using in this line:

```
$checkboxes += [$key1 => [["value" => $test]]];
```

Because `$checkboxes` contains the key `$key1` already in every iteration but the first one, it's not overwritten. With array union, the key on the left wins.

Instead push into the array:

```
$checkboxes[$key1][] = ["value" => $test];
```